# SHAP value transformation to probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, shapley-value

For my research project, I use SHAP values for plotting multiple diagrams to investigate the prediction process for a XGBoost and CatBoost model.

I wonder how `xgbc_explainer.expected_value` (also known as `expected_value`, `base_value` and `E[f(x)]`) is calculated. 
In my understanding, `E[f(x)]` is calculated by averaging the (probability) predictions, but I am not able to do it manually.

A similar question has already been asked within the repo and marked by the repo owner as a bug:
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1388

Since the bug is already more than two years old and has not yet been fixed, I decided to resolve the issue for my code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

import shap
# print the JS visualization code to the notebook
shap.initjs()

iris = datasets.load_iris()

data = iris.data
label = iris.target

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["feature0", "feature1", "feature2", "feature3"])
df["labels"] = label
df = df[(df["labels"] == 0) | (df["labels"] == 1)]
data = df[["feature0", "feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]]
label = df["labels"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, label, random_state=42)

xgbc = XGBClassifier(eval_metric='error', use_label_encoder = False)
xgbc.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = xgbc.predict(X_test)
y_pred_proba = xgbc.predict_proba(X_test)

xgbc_explainer = shap.Explainer(xgbc)
shap_values_xgbc_train = xgbc_explainer(X_train)
shap_values_xgbc_test = xgbc_explainer(X_test)

y_train_proba = xgbc.predict_proba(X_train)
print(f"My base-line is: {xgbc_explainer.expected_value:.3f} " + 
      f"and my average prediction is: {np.mean(y_train_proba[:,1]):.3f}")
# My base-line is: 0.165 and my average prediction is: 0.520


# Since xgbc_explainer.expected_value is not correct, I calculate the value manually:
shap_values_xgbc_test.base_values[:] = np.mean(y_train_proba[:,1])
xgbc_explainer.expected_value = np.mean(y_train_proba[:,1])

n = 5
display(shap.force_plot(shap_values_xgbc_test[n].base_values, shap_values_xgbc_test[n].values, X_test.iloc[[n]], link="identity"))
display(shap.force_plot(shap_values_xgbc_test[n].base_values, shap_values_xgbc_test[n].values, X_test.iloc[[n]], link="logit"))
```

Here are the [force_plots](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.force_plot.html) for link="identity" and link="logit":
[image: force_plots for link="identity" and link="logit"]

I know how I can calculate f(x) for the "identity" and the "logit" case:

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)) 


n = 5
f_x_identity = shap_values_xgbc_test[n].base_values + np.sum(shap_values_xgbc_test.values, axis=1)
print(f_x_identity[n])
# -3.2665708
f_x_logit = sigmoid(f_x_identity)
print(f_x_logit[n])
# 0.036735985
```

What is the correct way of transforming the SHAP values into probabilities? 
Is a linear transformation valid?

```
shap_values_proba = (shap_values_xgbc_test.values / np.sum(shap_values_xgbc_test.values, axis=1)[:,None] * (f_x_logit - sigmoid(shap_values_xgbc_test.base_values))[:,None])
```